# Rank PHP MySQL search results based on result sequence

Tags: mysql, relevance

I'd like to improve my MySQL search functionality. When searching "Fi" in my car database, I would like FIAT to be ranked first, as I feel a cars brand should have a higher rank than the model version. I want to tell MySQL if the search term matches the first letters of a Brand then prioritise that result first.

{[image: My Search results]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJKs3.png)

Here's my current code

```
$sql = "SELECT v.id, v.model, v.model_version, v.model_year, b.brand FROM vehicles v LEFT JOIN brands b ON v.brand_id = b.id WHERE CONCAT(b.brand, ' ', v.model, ' ', v.model_version) LIKE ? LIMIT 6";
```

Comment: This has no relation to JS, autocomplete, and little/none to PHP. You should look at full text indexing. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: Right! This seems to make sense. 
Tried this, but it doesnt work:
$sql = "SELECT v.id, v.model, v.model_version, v.model_year, b.brand FROM vehicles v
          LEFT JOIN brands b ON v.brand_id = b.id WHERE MATCH(b.brand, v.model, v.model_version) AGAINST (? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";

Comment: Did you create the index already? Can you define `doesnt work` a bit more? Doesn't give results, doesn't rank as expected, etc?

Comment: Index is created for brands, model and model_version. Error I am getting is "#1210 - Incorrect arguments to MATCH" As soon as I remove Brands, I get a result. So somehow it has issue with me adding brands to the mix.

Comment: Can you add result of `show create table brands`?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I understand what you mean? You want me to run that SQL alone?

Comment: Yes, that will show how the table is built and the index, and likely cause of 1210 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @user3783243 is the right answer.  If you want to do it with mysql, define a rank column along these lines: `4 * if(b.brand like ?, 1, 0) + 2 * if(v.model like ?, 1, 0) + if(v.model_version like ?, 1, 0) as 'rank'`.  It gets tricky quickly.  Let's say there is exact mach on the model but a partial match on the brand.  Should the partial brand really be ranked higher?

Comment: Thanks for this, it works. But you're right, it gets complicated quickly. Makes you quickly appreciate the complexity of googles search engine ha...

Comment: Please mark it solved if that answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best answer that works really well I believe. As full-text searches only index up to 4 characters (unless you change server settings) this can be a hassle.

Here was my approach:

```mysql
SELECT v.id, v.model, v.model_version, v.model_year, b.brand FROM vehicles v
          LEFT JOIN brands b ON v.brand_id = b.id
          WHERE (
            CONCAT(b.brand, ' ', v.model, ' ', v.model_version) LIKE 'fi%' OR
            CONCAT(b.brand, ' ', v.model, ' ', v.model_version) LIKE '%fi%' OR
            CONCAT(b.brand, ' ', v.model, ' ', v.model_version) LIKE '%fi'
          ) ORDER BY case
              WHEN CONCAT(b.brand, ' ', v.model, ' ', v.model_version) LIKE 'fi%' THEN 1
              WHEN CONCAT(b.brand, ' ', v.model, ' ', v.model_version) LIKE '%fi%' THEN 2
              WHEN CONCAT(b.brand, ' ', v.model, ' ', v.model_version) LIKE '%fi' THEN 3
            ELSE 4 END
          LIMIT 6
```

Comment: In the `where` clause you only need the `'%fi%'` case.  If you don't need your search to cover overlapping fields, you might get better performance if your `where` clause look at individual fields opposed to constructed one.  If you need the constructed column is a requirement, your query would cleaner with a common table expression.  I don't know if that has any performance impact. `with select v.id, CONCAT(b.brand, ' ', v.model, ' ', v.model_version) brand_model_version select ...  where brand_model_version like ...`

Comment: The above should have been `with t select v.id ... select id, brand_model_version from t where brand_model_version lile '%fi%'  order by ...`